# Why does R. Nachman b. Yitzchak say a blessing, and why does the Bavli include it? (שבת דף מו)‎

Tags: blessing, maseches-shabbos

The *Bavli*, *Shabas* 46:

> *Rav Aviya* came to *Rava*'s house; his boots were gross with clay. He set [them] on a bed in front of *Rava*. *Rava* minded; [*Rava*] wanted to bother him. [*Rava*] said to him: Why did *Raba* and *Rav Yosef* both say a naphtha lamp may also be moved [on *Shabas* after it's extinguished]? [*Rav Aviya*] answered: Because it is fit for covering a receptacle with. [*Rava* countered:] If so, all the pebbles in the courtyard may be moved, as they are fit for covering a receptacle with? [*Rav Aviya* answered:] This [lamp] has the status of a receptacle; those [pebbles] do not have the status of a receptacle. [And] hasn't it been taught that bracelets, nose rings, and rings are like any receptacle that may be moved in a courtyard, and *Ula* said why, because they have the status of a receptacle? Here, too, because it has the status of a receptacle.
>
> *Rav Nachman bar Yitzchak* said: Blessed be the Merciful that *Rava* did not shame *Rav Aviya*.

1. Is there anything to *Rav Nachman bar Yitzchak*'s blessing beyond the usual desire that no one be shamed? Why would be bad for *Rava* to shame *Rav Aviya* in this story beyond the usual reasons?
2. Why does the *Bavli* see fit to include this blessing of *Rav Nachman bar Yitzchak*'s?

(I suspect that the answer to #1, if affirmative, may help clarify #2 as well.)